# how enter in TextBox only digits from interval

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to make some form (C#, WinForms) for small program Reminder.
During it i have some problem - whant to make some filter for textBox where user must enter start time for event.
As result got next - on KeyPress event add some code, the allow enter only digits, but also i want that user can enter only digits from some diapasone.

code:

```
  private void starTimetextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar >= '0') && (e.KeyChar <= '9'))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char) (Keys.Enter))
                startTimeMMtextBox.Focus();
        }
        e.Handled = true;

    }
```

can i do this by using this event or no?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why not let the user to enter any value and report him Invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
    }
```

**NOTE:-** You can use TextBox's MaxLength property to restrict user to enter only 2 digits. To display message to user you can use TextChanged event of TextBox.

Comment: This won't prevent user from copy and paste text

Comment: bu how can i add some diapasone for this? as i understand this code allow to enter only digits and control keys, but also i would like to make some code that allow enter user only numbers between 0 and 24, can i do with this event/ or i must to write some separate method for this purpose?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel:- For preventing the user from cope and paste you can  set the ShortcutsEnabled property of textbox to false.

Comment: You forgot Paste option in context menu too. I'm just giving hint to OP so that he can know there are several loopholes.

Comment: @Kirill:- You cant restrict the user to enter only digits 1,2,3,4,5,6,....24 in a text box. But what you can do is you can restrict the user to enter only two digits and later you can apply certain checks to check if the number entered in the text box is in the range 0-24!!! :)

Comment: @Kirill:- **You can use TextBox's MaxLength property to restrict user to enter only 2 digits. To display message to user you can use TextChanged event of TextBox.**

Comment: got it! left this code for KeyPress Event and add some method, that concatinate all data from text box - add check for numbers in method `if ((Convert.ToInt16(timefromH)) >= 0 && ((Convert.ToInt16(timefromH)) <= 24))` like this - now it's ok

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi very usefull TextBox's MaxLength property! thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make a filter on the characters 0 to 9, you can extend the previous answer.
(Similair as in your question sample).

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                   && (e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9');
   }
```